# How to avoid clipping when animating transform in viewController transitionAnimation

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem with a custom animation viewController transition.

I have a collectionView (fromView) and when a cell is selected, it grows to fullSize (toView).

It's working great except for the bottom cells, they are cropped when animating to center.

I tried to change the frame of the containerView to get extra space to aboid the crop but it's messing up the positions of the viewcontrollers in it.

This is the relevant code for the transition and a sketch to spot the issue.

Many thanks.

Actual behaviour:
[image][image]
Expected:
[image]

// originFrame is define by the selected cell in fromView
    var originFrame = CGRect.zero

```
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {


        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to),
                    let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)
                    else { return }

        let finalFrame = toView.frame
        let growFactor = finalFrame.width / originFrame.width

        let centerDiffX = fromView.center.x-originFrame.midX
        let centerDiffY = fromView.center.y-originFrame.midY


        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration,
            delay:0.0,
            animations: {

                let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: growFactor, y: growFactor)
                fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: deltaX, y: deltaY).concatenating(scaleTransform)

                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a snapshot of the collectionview do the trick ;)